# Find the longest flat subsection in array?

Tags: algorithm

Can somebody tell me what is the longest flat subsection?

Comment: A mind-reader might be able to.

Comment: I think you definitely should have attended the CS class.

Comment: Where did you get this formulation? Please, provide some background. Are you talking about a one-dimensional array? Of integer, real or complex numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by longest flat subsection? Finding the longest constant or monotonous subsequence in a sequence is trivial.

Comment: Thanks everyone for reply my post. Actually I am studying in Theory of computer software and I read the lesson and I met the exercise like that:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Given an array a[0:n) (n≧0), its subsection a[p,q)  (0≦p≦q≦n) is called “flat” if ∀i,j:p≦i≦j＜q:a[i]＝a[j].  Derive a correct program that stores the length of the longest flat subsection into a variable m.

Comment: This is not a standard term. You have to include the definition in the question in such a case. Please edit.

Comment: This lesson is call " Program Derivation ", mean that we have to write a correct program by finding (1) Post condition, (2) Pre-condition, (3) Loop Invariant, and the code is based on these 3 property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given an array a[0:n) (n≧0), its subsection a[p,q) (0≦p≦q≦n) is called “flat” if ∀i,j:p≦i≦j＜q:a[i]＝a[j].

tranlsates to english as "a subsequence is considered flat if and only if all elements within the sequence are equal to each other". Since equality is transitive, reflexive and symmetric, you can find it as:

```
pre: a is a sequence of symbols
     n is its length

last = null
bestAt = null
bestLen = -1
for each i in 0..n-1
  if a[i] != last
    thisAt = i
    thisLen = 1
    last=a[i]
    if thisLen > bestLen
      bestLen = thisLen
      bestAt = thisAt
  else
    thisLen++
  last=a[i]

post: a is not modified
      n is not modified
      bestAt holds the position of the first longest subsequence
      bestLen holds the length of the first longest subsequence
```

Comment: You could remove the dependence on `==` being symmetric by changing `if a[i] != last` to `if not last == a[i]`. You could remove the dependence on reflexivity by testing each element against itself. Removing the dependence on transitivity would require `Omega(k^2)` comparisons instead of `O(n)`, where `k` is the longest subsequence that satisfies a weakened condition of "transitive flatness".

Comment: @SteveJessop no. removing the dependence on symmetry would need two comparisons. Applying anyways.

Comment: I don't think it does, because the definition of flatness only requires `a[i] == a[j]` when `i <= j`, not when `j < i`. So the only way in which your code depends on symmetry is that you happen to have put the lower-indexed item on the RHS of the comparison. Sorry, I didn't mean to recommend that you change the code, I think it's only a matter for idle curiosity what to do about relations that use the symbol `=` despite not being equivalence relations!

Comment: @SteveJessop oops, you're right. The definition assumes reflexivity anyways.

Comment: @SteveJessop also note that _equivalence_ is _defined_ as a symmetric, transitive and reflexive relation. _Equality_ is defined as a symmetric, antisymmetric and reflexive relation (symmetry and antisymmetry imply transitivity).

Comment: Actually I am the beginner of this course so I don't know well about that lesson so Thanks you for your answer..

Comment: @SteveJessop For asymmetric (or irreflexive) equality, the translation to english needs to be adjusted as well ;-)

Comment: @Jan: sure, it would be naughty to refer to a relation as "equality" if it didn't have those properties. I just noticed that your code doesn't rely on them very heavily (except transitivity), and so your code could be generalized to other relations quite easily.